# Desired State Configuration Verbose Logging

Tags: dsc

When attempting to debug issues with Desired State Configuration, I've found the following command invaluable;

```
start-dscconfiguration -wait -verbose -useexisting
```

This will (obviously) allow viewing of all the verbose logs.

The problem is that if the server needs to reboot as part of the configuration, or - more importantly - it's running normally (e.g. non-interactively as part of a pull configuration) it's not as easy to view these logs.

Is there any way to get the /exact/ same output logged to a specific location?

I do not have any .json files in the `C:\Windows\system32\configuration\configurationstatus` folder as suggested in one of the answers?

Comment: Is there a way to get Info or warning logs instead of Verbose?

Answer (score 1):

Set `RebootNodeIfNeeded` to false in meta configuration:

```
[DscLocalConfigurationManager()]
configuration Settings
{
    Settings
    {
        ActionAfterReboot  = 'StopConfiguration'
        RebootNodeIfNeeded = $false
    }
}
```

And run the existing configuration again:

```
Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -UseExisting -Verbose
```

(Adding this for posterity as other answers only contain links.)
Source: http://nanalakshmanan.com/blog/DSC-get-job-details-post-reboot/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps outlined in this blog to get the results post a reboot http://nanalakshmanan.com/blog/DSC-get-job-details-post-reboot/

Answer (score -1):

You can also view the historical job logs as described in this blog http://nanalakshmanan.com/blog/Historical-Job-Logs/

Comment: I've taken a look at your article and while it would seem to have been the solution it suggests that there should be .json files in the following location;

C:\Windows\system32\configuration\configurationstatus

I've taken a look across a number of DSC clients and servers, and on each of them there only appear to be .mof files in this location. I did a quick Google to see if anything could be done to enable the creation of these .json files, but came back empty - is there something that needs to be done to enable these? I've looked across both WMF 4 and WMF 5 clients.

Comment: It is not available on WMF 4 but is available on WMF 5.0 RTM. Can you share the output of your $PSVersionTable?

Comment: `PSVersion                      5.0.10514.6`

Comment: You are using WMF 5.0 PP which doesn't have this feature. You will have to upgrade to WMF 5.0 RTM https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395 to be able to see .json file.

Comment: You should put details in your answer and not only put a link to your blog.